# How to correctly wrap a row of buttons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a Flutter beginner. I'm currently trying to build a row of (custom) buttons that wraps down to a new line when the buttons overflow.

This is how the button should look like.

[image]

I've currently used a **Wrap** widget and its children are a bunch of **CustomToggleButton**.

```dart
Wrap(
  children: [
    CustomToggleButton(
      title: "general".tr,
      controller: controller,
    ),
    CustomToggleButton(
    // ...
    ),
  ],
),
```

The problem is that it looks correct and works fine, but the debug console keeps telling me to put the **Flexible** widget in a **Row**, **Column**, or **Flex** widget, which I have tried and failed.

This is the implementation of the **CustomToggleButton**:

```dart
class CustomToggleButton extends StatefulWidget {
  // default things
}

class _CustomToggleButtonState extends State<CustomToggleButton> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
    return Flexible(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          animateColor();
          widget.controller.toggleSelected(widget.title);
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: animation.value,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                widget.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: textAnimation.value,
                  fontSize: 10,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So I want to know if there's any way to mitigate this issue, or it's just unavoidable and I have to redesign the button.

Comment: Try using Expanded instead of Flexible in CustomToggleButton class.

Comment: @AsimBhadra Unfortunately, that does not help, because **Expanded**, **Flexible**, and **Spacer** widgets have to be put in either a **Row**, **Column**, or **Flex** widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `Flexible` from the class worked fine.

```
class CustomButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomButtonState createState() => _CustomButtonState();
}

class _CustomButtonState extends State<CustomButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
          ),
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              'widget.title',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 10,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

And Wrap as follows:

```
Wrap(
                    children: [
                      const CustomButton(),
                      const CustomButton(),
                      const CustomButton(),
                      const CustomButton(),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: This is the right solution, I honestly should have thought about not using it in the first place :p thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use GridView because it have grid delegate that you can use to range your button.

```
GridView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
    left: 16, right: 16, top: 16, bottom: 16),
  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  gridDelegate:
    const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      mainAxisSpacing: 50.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 50.0,
      childAspectRatio: 1.0,
    ),
 children: List<Widget>.generate(),
),
```

You can see here the doc for more information https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html

Comment: That solution differs from what I wanted, since I want the buttons to have different sizes depending on the its content text, and I also only want it to go to a new line once it overflows, otherwise it would be a single row.